# Lego gear ratios

Tags: code-golf, math

I'm building a giant lego robot and I need to generate some particular gear ratios using a set of gears.  I have lots of gears with the common lego gear sizes: 8, 16, 24, or 40 teeth.  Write a program I can use where I input a gearing ratio and the program tells me what combination of gears I should use to get the requested ratio.

The input ratio will be specified on standard input (or your language's equivalent) with two integers separated by a colon.  A ratio of `a:b` means that the output shaft should turn `a/b` times as fast as the input shaft.

The output to standard output should be a single line containing a space-separated list of gear ratios, in the form of `x:y` where `x` is the size of the gear on the input shaft and `y` is the size of the gear on the output shaft.  You must use the minimum possible number of gears for the given ratio.  Each `x` and `y` must be one of `8,16,24,40`.

examples:

```
1:5 -> 8:40
10:1 -> 40:8 16:8
9:4 -> 24:16 24:16
7:1 -> IMPOSSIBLE
7:7 ->
6:15 -> 16:40
```

If the desired gear ratio is impossible, print "IMPOSSIBLE".  If no gears are required, print the empty string.

This is code golf, shortest answer wins.

Comment: Aren't the ratio of teeth inversely proportional to the angular velocity?  So, for example if the desired input output velocity is 1:5, shouldn't the ratio be 40:8 instead of 8:40?  Or is the left-hand ratio the effective gear teeth to actual gear teeth ratio you want?

Comment: Interesting question... `1:5 -> 8:40` and `10:1 -> 40:8` make sense but the others not so much.

Comment: @DavidCarraher: I guess you can define it either way.  I tried to be internally consistent.  `1:5` means the output shaft turns 5 times slower, and an 8 tooth gear on the input and a 40 tooth gear on the output makes that happen.

Comment: @MikeDtrick: well, `10:1 -> 40:8 16:8`, not what you said.  What about the others confuses you?  `9:4` is implemented doing `3:2` twice.  `3:2` is implemented using `24:16`.

Comment: If one gear has 40 teeth and the other has 8 teeth, isn't the ratio `5:1`?  The second example is confusing me... `7:7` yields impossible, correct?

Comment: @MikeDtrick: Yes to your first question.  To get 10:1 you can do 5:1 (using 40 teeth / 8 teeth) and then 2:1 (using 16 teeth / 8 teeth).  `7:7` is the same as `1:1`, so it requires no gears to implement.

Comment: Isn't 7:1 possible with infinitely many gears... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Python - 204

Ok, I'll go first:

```python
def p(n,a=[1]*9):
 n=int(n)
 for i in(2,3,5):
    while n%i<1:n/=i;a=[i]+a
 return a,n
(x,i),(y,j)=map(p,raw_input().split(':'))
print[' '.join(`a*8`+':'+`b*8`for a,b in zip(x,y)if a!=b),'IMPOSSIBLE'][i!=j]
```

edit:

To 'optimize' the output, this can be added before the `print` statement,

```python
for e in x:
 if e in y:x.remove(e);y.remove(e)
```

bringing the total up to **266 characters**, I believe.

Comment: `<1` can replace `==0`. Also, `if b:a=...return a` can be `return b and...or a`.

Comment: Doesn't work for, e.g., `23:12`.

Comment: Well spotted. It goes through since 12 is dividable. Adding `elif i!=1:return[]` to the original solves the problem but introduces another one. `$ python gears.py <<< 21:28` => `24:16`.. I'm gonna look into it. Looks like the problem wasn't so simple after all :D I Think the code has to be even longer, or I need another approach.

Comment: There you go; I think this one works as expected. Even made it smaller :)

Comment: Looks pretty good, but it isn't optimal.  `6:15` can be done with `16:40` but your code returns `24:40 16:24`.

Comment: Now with 'optimization' ;)

Answer (score 4):

## Perl - <strike>310 306 294 288</strike> 272

I'm a little rusty with perl and never did a code-golf... but no excuses. Char-count is without line-breaks. Using perl v5.14.2 .

```
($v,$n)=<>=~/(.+):(.+)/;
($x,$y)=($v,$n);($x,$y)=($y,$x%$y)while$y;
sub f{$p=shift;$p/=$x;for(5,3,2){
while(!($p%$_)){$p/=$_;push@_,$_*8}}
$o="IMPOSSIBLE"if$p!=1;
@_}
@a=f($v);@b=f($n);
if(!$o){for(0..($#b>$#a?$#b:$#a)){
$a[$_]||=8;
$b[$_]||=8;
push@_,"$a[$_]:$b[$_]"}}
print"$o@_\n"
```

I'm looking forward to critics and hints. It's not so easy to find tips and tricks for code-golf (in perl).

Comment: You can save 9 chars by removing `$1:$2 -> `, it is not required in the output.

Comment: Oh, I misread the spec. Thanks.

Comment: You can reduce statements like `$a[$_]=8 if!$a[$_];` to `$a[$_]||=8;`

Comment: Newlines count as one character.

Comment: The first line can be abbreviated to `($v,$n)=split/:|\s/,<>;` (untested).

Comment: `=` associates rightward, so you can fold the first two lines together as `($x,$y)=($v,$n)=...`. And you should I think be able to skip the sigils.

Comment: @Timtech The newlines are only there for human readability.

Comment: Okay. +1 btw :)

Answer (score 2):

## C, <strike>246</strike> <strike>216</strike> 213 bytes

In a (futile) attempt to beat my own Prolog solution, I completely rewrote the C solution.

```
b,c,d;f(a,b,p){while(c=a%5?a%3?a%2?1:2:3:5,d=b%5?b%3?b%2?1:2:3:5,c*d>1)c<2|b%c?d<2|a%d?p&&printf("%d:%d ",8*c,8*d):(c=d):(d=c),a/=c,b/=d;c=a-b;}main(a){scanf("%d:%d",&a,&b);f(a,b,0);c?puts("IMPOSSIBLE"):f(a,b,1);}
```

My original C solution (246 bytes):

```
#define f(c,d) for(;a%d<1;a/=d)c++;for(;b%d<1;b/=d)c--;
b,x,y,z;main(a){scanf("%d:%d",&a,&b);f(x,2)f(y,3)f(z,5)if(a-b)puts("IMPOSSIBLE");else
while((a=x>0?--x,2:y>0?--y,3:z>0?--z,5:1)-(b=x<0?++x,2:y<0?++y,3:z<0?++z,5:1))printf("%d:%d ",a*8,b*8);}
```

It was a nice exercise to prove it can be done without building lists.

Answer (score 2):

## swi-prolog, <strike>324</strike> <strike>250</strike> <strike>248</strike> 204 bytes

Prolog does pretty well at solving a problem like this.

```
m(P):-(g(P,L),!;L='IMPOSSIBLE'),write(L).
g(A:A,''):-!.
g(A:B,L):-A/C/X,C>1,B/C/Y,!,g(X:Y,L);A/C/X,!,B/D/Y,C*D>1,g(X:Y,T),format(atom(L),'~D:~D ~a',[C*8,D*8,T]).
X/Y/Z:-(Y=5;Y=3;Y=2;Y=1),Z is X//Y,Y*Z>=X.
```

Input is passed as a term parameter to predicate `m`. Output is written to stdout. Sorry about the trailing 'true'; that's just the interpreter's way of letting me know everything was fine.

```
?- m(54:20).
24:40 24:16 24:8 
true.

?- m(7:7).
true.

?- m(7:1).
IMPOSSIBLE
true.
```

Answer (score 2):

### Pyth, 101 bytes

```
D'HJH=Y[)VP30W!%JN=/JN=Y+NY))R,YJ;IneKhm'vdcz\:J"IMPOSSIBLE").?V.t,.-Y.-hK=J.-hKYJ1In.*Npj\:m*8d_Np\
```

An implementation of [@daniero' python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7148/32686) but semi-optimised for Pyth.

```
D'H                               - Define a function (') which takes an argument, H.
   JH                             - J = H (H can't be changed in the function)
     =Y[)                         - Y = []
         V                        - For N in ...
          P30                     - Prime factors of 30 (2,3,5)
             W!%JN                - While not J%N
                  =/JN            - J /= N
                      =Y+NY       - Y = N + Y
                           ))R,YJ - To start of function, return [Y,J]

ENDFUNCTION

If 
         cz\:  - Split the input by the ':'
     m'vd      - ['(eval(d)) for d in ^]
   Kh          - Set K to the first element of the map (before the :)
  e            - The second returned value
             J - The second returned value after the : (The variables are globals)
 n             - Are not equal

Then 
"IMPOSSIBLE" - Print "IMPOSSIBLE"

Else
V                                      - For N in
 .t                1                   - transpose, padded with 1's
             .-hKY                     - 1st function first return - 2nd function first return
           =J                          - Set this to J
       .-hK                            - 1st function first return - ^
    .-Y                                - 2nd function first return - ^
   ,              J                    - [^, J]
                                         (Effectively XOR the 2 lists with each other)
                    I                  - If
                     n.*N              - __ne__(*N) (if n[0]!=n[1])
                         pj\:m*8d_N    - print ":".join([`d*8` for d in reversed(N)])
                                   p\  - print a space seperator
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=D%27HJH%3DY%5B%29VP30W!%25JN%3D%2FJN%3DY%2BNY%29%29R%2CYJ%3BIneKhm%27vdcz%3AJ%22IMPOSSIBLE%22%29.%3FV.t%2C.-Y.-hK%3DJ.-hKYJ1In.*Npj%3Am*8d_Np+&input=9%3A4&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%3A5&debug=0)

[Or test every case](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=D%27HJH%3DY%5B%29VP30W!%25JN%3D%2FJN%3DY%2BNY%29%29R%2CYJ%3BIneKhm%27vdcz%3AJ%22IMPOSSIBLE%22%29.%3FV.t%2C.-Y.-hK%3DJ.-hKYJ1In.*Npj%3Am*8d_Np+&input=9%3A4&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%3A5%0A10%3A1%0A9%3A4%0A7%3A1%0A7%3A7%0A6%3A15&debug=1)

Answer (score 0):

### ES6, 230 bytes

```
x=>([a,b]=x.split`:`,f=(x,y)=>y?f(y,x%y):x,g=f(a,b),d=[],a/=g,f=x=>{while(!(a%x))a/=x,d.push(x*8)},[5,3,2].map(f),c=d,d=[],a*=b/g,[5,3,2].map(f),a>1?'IMPOSSIBLE':(c.length<d.length?d:c).map((_,i)=>(c[i]||8)+':'+(d[i]||8)).join` `)
```

One of my longest golfs, so I must have done something wrong... Ungolfed:

```
x => {
    [a, b] = x.split(":");
    f = (x, y) => y ? f(y, x % y) : x; // GCD
    g = f(a, b);
    f = x => {
        r = [];
        while (!(x % 5)) { x /= 5; r.push(5); }
        while (!(x % 3)) { x /= 3; r.push(3); }
        while (!(x % 2)) { x /= 2; r.push(2); }
        if (x > 1) throw "IMPOSSIBLE!";
        return r;
    }
    c = f(a);
    d = f(b);
    r = [];
    for (i = 0; c[i] || d[i]; i++) {
        if (!c[i]) c[i] = 8;
        if (!d[i]) d[i] = 8;
        r[i] = c[i] + ":" + d[i];
    }
    return r.join(" ");
}
```